# Eval and href attribute?

Tags: asp.net, eval, href

Can you explain please what is occurring in this asp row?

```
<a href="AddItem.aspx?c=<%# Eval("CollectionID") %>">[edit item]</a>
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: This old question isn't clear, and was not edited following a request for clarification, so I am going to try to vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an HTML anchor tag which has embedded in the `href` attribute an [ASP.NET binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

In this case, the binding expression evaluates a property called `CollectionID`.

It is not clear exactly what you don't understand about it, so without further information, this is all I can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are in asp.net webforms repeater that has an object with a CollectionID property.
This is setting the c parameter to the actual collection id for the current row of the repeater.